# Deleting elements of an array from a particular index to the end till there is a valid element

Tags: perl

Hi i have this array say

```
name[0] =  hello
name[1] = bye
name[2] = ok
name[3] = wassup
and so on....
```

i want to pop the elements from the index 2 to the end of the array because i want to replace them with new ones.I am running a loop so cant keep track of the individual indices but would be able to keep track of the element 2.So how could i pop the elements from 2 onwards to the rest till the array is defines ?

i was using

```
delete array[2,..]
```

is this valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) function is for; just do `splice @array, 2;`.

Answer (score 0):

Assign an array slice to itself:

```
@array = @array[0,1];
```

Comment: If `@array` has less than 2 elements, this expression will add elements to it.

Comment: @mob : True, but the OP makes it clear that their list has more than two elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @array = ( ... stuff ...);
@array = @array[0 .. 1];
```

Just take what you want and leave the rest.

You might be considering matching against a certain array value:

```
my @array = ( stuff );
my @rest;

for (0 .. $#array) {
    if ($array[$_] =~ /^ok$/) { push @rest, @array[$_ .. $#array]; last }
}
```